# SQL: calculate MAU by window function

Tags: sql, window-functions, vertica

I'm trying unsuccessfully to calculate a MAU- monthly distinct active users, by using window functions.
**I need the calculation for each day during the month, for the preceding 30 days**

This is what I have so far:

```
select 
  t.datee
, t.app,i.sourcee
, i.campaign
, t.mobile
, sum(count(distinct t.user_id)) over (
     PARTITION BY 
       date_trunc('month',datee)
     , t.app
    , i.sourcee
    , i.campaign
    , t.mobile 
    ORDER BY datee asc 
    ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
FROM dim_x i
JOIN agg_y t
  ON  i.app=t.app
 AND i.mobile=t.mobile
WHERE t.datee>=CURRENT_DATE-30
  AND t.datee<CURRENT_DATE  
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
order by 1 desc
```

But all I get is a sum of active users by all days instead of sum of distinct users.  I'm using Vertica db.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to use a window function here along with `GROUP BY`?  Any sample data might also be helpful.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I need it in order to get values by the key which is these 5 fields: 
datee,  app, sourcee, campaign, mobile

Comment: I just reformatted it to make it readable. But there seems to be an issue with the last expression in the SELECT list: `t.mobile order by datee asc ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`; this seems to be a mutilated OLAP window function expression. Can you look at it?

Comment: reformatted it again a second time. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting, really, why you should need an OLAP expression for that.

Aren't you looking for the total number of distinct users per:

- year-month combination out of datee
- app
- sourcee (whatever that might be)
- campaign
- mobile (probably mobile number)

?

A simple GROUP BY would do, as far as I'm concerned. If I disregard sourcee, campaign and mobile, selecting just from one table: `input` for argument's sake, with some sample data I just made up, this query:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(datee) * 100 + MONTH(datee) AS yearmonth
, app
, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS monthly_active_users
FROM input
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
;
```

... would return:

```
YEARMONTH|app  |monthly_active_users
  201,601|app-a|                   2
  201,601|app-b|                   2
  201,602|app-a|                   2
  201,602|app-b|                   2
  201,603|app-a|                   2
  201,603|app-b|                   2
  201,604|app-a|                   2
  201,604|app-b|                   2
  201,605|app-a|                   2
  201,605|app-b|                   2
  201,606|app-a|                   1
  201,606|app-b|                   1
```

Just editing my previous answer. You seem to need the running COUNT DISTINCT of user id-s , partitioned by several expressions.

With the input from the WITH clause below, would you need a report like this (only showing the first 12 rows of 53, ordered by datee, app)?

```
datee     |app  |user_id |running_active_users
2016-01-01|app-a|arthur  |                   1
2016-01-04|app-b|ford    |                   1
2016-01-07|app-a|trillian|                   2
2016-01-10|app-b|zaphod  |                   2
2016-01-13|app-a|arthur  |                   2
2016-01-16|app-b|ford    |                   2
2016-01-19|app-a|trillian|                   2
2016-01-22|app-b|zaphod  |                   2
2016-01-25|app-a|arthur  |                   2
2016-01-28|app-b|ford    |                   2
2016-01-31|app-a|trillian|                   2
2016-02-03|app-b|zaphod  |                   2
```

?

If that's the case, I don't see the reason for existence of your GROUP BY clause, though.

Below is the query with GROUP BY as above with test data returning the results above in a WITH clause. Regard that input as the join between your two tables.

```
WITH
input(datee,app,user_id) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2016-01-01','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-04','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-07','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-10','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-25','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-28','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-04','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-25','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-09','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-30','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-06','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-09','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-15','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-06-05','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-13','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-16','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-31','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-03','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-06','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-09','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-12','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-15','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-18','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-21','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-24','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-02-27','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-01','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-10','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-13','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-16','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-28','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-31','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-06','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-12','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-15','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-27','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-03','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-27','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-30','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-19','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-01-22','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-07','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-19','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-03-22','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-03','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-18','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-21','app-b','ford'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-04-24','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-12','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-18','app-a','trillian'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-21','app-b','zaphod'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-05-24','app-a','arthur'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2016-06-02','app-b','zaphod'
)
SELECT
  YEAR(datee) * 100 + MONTH(datee) AS YEARMONTH
, app
, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS monthly_active_users
FROM input
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Comment: I actually need a calculation foreach day during the month, for the entire preceding 30 days for it.

Comment: Some sort of a running `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`, then? Well, Vertica does not offer the analytic `COUNT(DISTINCT <x>)` function. Need to dig a bit to find the workaround

Comment: I'll edit my initial answer to show a possible output you could need.